# Normal subgroups closed under operation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Prove that if N and H are normal subgroups of a group G then the set NH is closed under the operation of G. Hint: Use conjugation.

If N and H are normal subgroups, that means they are invariant under conjugation by G, and $NH=\{nh:n\in N, h\in H\}.$ If $x,y\in NH$, then $xy=n_1h_1n_2h_2$, where $n_1,n_2\in N,h_1,h_2\in H$. I am not sure how to finish this proof, are normal subgroups closed under the operation of G? Because I could show that $NH$ is normal, I don't know if that would be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to show that you can write $n_1h_1n_2h_2=nh$, ie as an element of $NH$. But if $H$ is normal, that means you can say $n_2^{-1}h_1n_2=h_3$ for some $h_3\in H$. Rearranging this last equation a bit and subbing into the original will give you your claim.

Also, to answer your question, every subgroup is closed under the inherited group operation, and this is necessary for the subgroup to be a group in its own right.

Comment: One may note that you only need *one* of the two subgroups to be normal.

Comment: Would it be enough to say that $n_1h_1n_2h_2=n_1n_2h_1h_2\in NH$ since $n_1n_2\in N$ and $h_1h_2\in H$?

Comment: If you knew the elements commuted, yes, but what you have written is false in general. That's why I had to introduce $h_3$, because that's all normality gives you.

Comment: oh yes, then you get that $n_1n_2h_3h_2 \in NH$ because $n_1n_2\in N$ and $h_3h_2 \in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $n_1h_1n_2h_2= n_1n_2(n_2^{-1}h_1n_2)h_2$, so ...
You even have that for any $g \in G$, and any $n \in N$ and $h \in H$, $g^{-1}nhg \in NH$, since $g^{-1}nhg=g^{-1}ng \cdot g^{-1}hg$. So $NH \unlhd G$.

Comment: This is the approach I wanted to take, but does this imply closure of $NH$ under the operation of $G$?